# Save image path in database using angularjs

Tags: javascript, sql, asp.net, angularjs, asp.net-mvc-4

I Have uploaded my image in local folder using angular file-model and returning the path using json but i am unable to save the path to database. Please help me to solve this issue. I am using .success method to return the response data to a hidden field to store it in database but it shows ERROR:" Cannot read property 'success' of undefined ".

**services.js:**

```
service.UploadFile = function (file) {
    var fd = new FormData();
    fd.append('file', file);
    $http.post('/Empdet/UploadFile', fd, {
        transformRequest: angular.identity,
        headers: { 'Content-Type': undefined }
    })
    .success(function () {
    })
    .error(function () {
    });
}

return service;
```

**Controller.js:**

```
 $scope.UploadFile = function () {
    console.log('UploadFile');
    console.log($scope.Empdet.PhotoFile);
    EmployeeFactory.UploadFile($scope.Empdet.PhotoFile).success(function (response) {
        console.log('response.IsSuccessful');
        console.log(response.Data);

        $scope.IsSuccessful = response.IsSuccessful;
        if ($scope.IsSuccessful) {
            $scope.PhotoText = response.Data;
            console.log('$scope.PhotoText');
            console.log($scope.PhotoText);                   
            $scope.CanClearMessage = true;
        } else {
            $scope.SuccessMessage = '';
            $scope.ErrorMessage = response.ReasonForFailure;
            $scope.CanClearMessage = true;
        }
    }
)};
```

**CreateNewEmployee.cshtml:**

```
 <tr>
    <td style="text-align: left;">
        <label class="labelsytle">
            PhotoFile
        </label>
    </td>
    <td style="text-align: left;">
        <input class="form-control" type="file" file-model="Empdet.PhotoFile" style="border-radius: 5px;"/>  
        <td><button class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="UploadFile()" style="border-radius: 5px; font-family: Consolas;">UPLOAD</button></td>
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    @*<td style="text-align: left;">
           <label class="labelsytle">
            PhotoText
        </label>
    </td>*@
    <td style="text-align: left;">
        <input class="form-control" type="hidden" name="search" ng-model="Empdet.PhotoText" placeholder="Enter PhotoText" style="border-radius: 5px;" />
    </td>
</tr>
```

**EmpdetController.cs:**

```
[HttpPost]
    public ActionResult UploadFile()
    {
        var file = Request.Files[0];
        var path = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/Photos/") + file.FileName);
        file.SaveAs(path);

        // prepare a relative path to be stored in the database and used to display later on.
        path = Url.Content(Path.Combine("~/Photos/" + file.FileName));
        // save to db
        return Json(path.ToString(), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `.then` function instead of `.success`

Replace your `.success` and `.error` code block with below code

```
.then(function (d) {
//Success callback

 }, function (error) {
     //Failed Callback

     alert('Error!');  

 });
```